# How can I get `column-gap`'s effect with `display: flex` in Chrome?

Tags: css, flexbox

According to this[0](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_column-gap_flex_context), Chrome doesn't support `column-gap` with `display: flex`.

Unfortunately, I have to support Chrome too.

What's the cleanest way to have the gap in Chrome without messing with Firefox (which understands `column-gap` with `display: flex` properly)?

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  colum-gap: 10px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>
```

The above displays fine in Firefox, with a 10px gutter between .flex-item elements. Chrome has no such gap because it can't do `column-gap` on `display: flex`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Added some code to illustrate.

Comment: Then you would have to use `margin` instead....but it's not going to be precise.

Comment: My issue with `margin` is that it adds it to every element, so one ends up with a margin when it shouldn't have one (the first one or the last one, depending on whether you use `margin-left` or `margin-right`)

Comment: Yep, well that's the issue. There is no *direct* substitute without JS until chrome decides to support the property. You'll just have to make do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.flex-item {
  flex-basis: 33%;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  }
.flex-item:first-child{
  margin-left: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
:root{
--gutter-size:.3em;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items:center;
}
.flex > * {
    margin: var(--gutter-size);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <h1>lorem</h1>
  <p>ipsume</p>
  <div>Dolor</div>
</div>
```